# Error while installing Azure CLI on CentOS 6.6

Tags: azure, centos6

How do I install azure CLI on CentOS 6.6.

```
python -V -> Python 2.6.6
which python -> /usr/bin/python 

/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -V -> Python 2.7.13

curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
```

**ERROR: The CLI does not support Python versions less than 2.7.**

How do i get the above script to take the python 2.7 installed.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install python2.7 from SCL. If you don't want to build something or want to have python2.6 as default in your CentOS.

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install python27

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable python27 bash
```

More information [here](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/).

Answer (score 1):

Azure CLI 2.0 need python 2.7. I test in my Centos 6.8 VM. Python 2.6 could not upgrade 2.7. So, as Khaled said, you need download python 2.7 and install it.

Please refer to following steps:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools" ##If you meet error, ignore it
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel
##download python 2.7 and install it
cd /opt
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && make altinstall
##create link
ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Then, you need edit $PATH, add `/usr/local/bin` to `/etc/profile` like below

```
# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /usr/local/bin
    pathmunge /sbin
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
else
```

Then `source /etc/profile`

Check the result.

```
[root@shui bin]# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/wiki/installing-python-2.7-on-centos-6.3.-follow-this-sequence-exactly-for-centos-machine-only).

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one solution:

1. Download the install script and modify it to use the full path of python interpreter `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` to avoid any ambiguouities where calling python. Then, you can run the modified install script.
2. Create a link to the newer python interpreter and place it in a position earlier within `$PATH` environment variable. So, the first instance will be used which will refer to newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the Azure CLI 2 Python 2.7 dependency and CentOS 6.x incompatibility is the use the Azure CLI Docker image:

[Run Azure CLI 2.0 in a Docker Container | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/run-azure-cli-docker?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Please describe the essential points of your answer, so it will still be useful when the link goes away.